# Scan for arbitrary targets (TYPE,METHOD,FIELD) annotated with custom @Annotation on spring (boot) startup

Tags: java, spring

I need to find all occurrences of my `@CustomAnnotation` (ideally ANY target) somewhere during Spring (boot) initialization - it can be event like `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` or `ApplicationContextAware`.

`ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` won't do it for me since it scans for annotation on class, before it's loaded (it reads metadata).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stay with pure spring (or boot) solution, but I had to revert to my old friend - Reflection (with Guava).

To make the work as seamless as possible I used: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Made a call (like in example github link above) through `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`.

Solves my problem easily, but I am open to pure-spring solutions if such exist (Guava is an additional dependency and maybe Spring already ships with something by default?).